# Change in area of a disk near black hole?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

I know that the length contraction can be determined by the formula:  $L\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{Rc^2}}$

But how can we calculate the decrement in area due to the black hole??

Suppose we have a disc of area ($\pi r^2$), where $r$ is large enough so that different point in the disc experience length contraction by different amount.

So what will be the formula for decrease in area due to length contraction caused by Black hole.(for the above stated situation)??

Comment: read this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: are you asking about gravitational length contraction, caused by the gravitational field of the BH?

Comment: Yes, it' effect on a disc